# Prevent EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE in specific case

Tags: craft3, php, password

I have a registration form and its custom validation in PHP plugin code.

However, the validation works when user set a new password.
I supposed that $event->isNew is good to detect if it is a new user registration or not, but the element does not work.
Craft says it is unknown property.

Could you tell me how to detect the kinds of submission?

```
// Registration Form
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
Event::on(
    User::class,
    Element::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE,
    function (Event $event) use($request) {
        // If a user already logged in we are not on the public registration page
        if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()) return;

        if (!$event->isNew) return;

        // Do the custom validation
        if (!$event->sender->firstName) {
            $event->sender->addError('firstName', Craft::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.', [ 'attribute' => Craft::t('app', 'First Name') ]));
            $event->isValid = false;
        }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should test the `sender` property pointing to the `User` element.

Second, there's no such property as `isNew` in that case.

However, you could test that user is new given that its ID won't be set in case the user has not been saved yet.

Something like:

```php
Event::on(
    User::class, // \craft\elements\User
    User::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE,
    function (\yii\base\ModelEvent $event) {
        $sender = $event->sender;
        Craft::debug("User " . ($sender->id ? "already exists" : "is new"), __METHOD__);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question.
Since I would like to use if user is new or not later, I edited the code like this.

```
$sender_id = $event->sender->id;
if ($sender_id) $is_new = false; else $is_new = true;
```